# Declare list elements as symbols sympy python

Tags: python, sympy

I've got a function that returns some list elements under some conditions :

```
 m1=   [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
 m2=   [[2, 0], [0, 2]]
```

And what I would like to do is declare m1 and m2 as symbols containing those indices, i.e m1[0] is the symbol [1,0],  using Sympy, but I am unsuccesful in my attempts so far.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You need to convert them to strings? If yes, use str() like this str(m1[0]) will return "[1, 0]".

Comment: @nacholibre No I mean symbols using Sympy, not string types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use [symarray](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/matrices/matrices.html?highlight=array#sympy.matrices.matrices.symarray).

```
from sympy import symarray

m1 = symarray('', 2)
m1[0] = [1, 0]
```

Comment: Using this has broken my original code giving error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
But I can see where the erorr is may thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know how I can append items? At the moment I can only get it to take the first value.

Comment: Not sure I get your question, but you can do: `m1 = numpy.append(m1, symarray('', 1)); m1[2] = [1, 1]`.

Comment: Also, it might be worth going through the implementation of the `symarray` function; look [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/_modules/sympy/matrices/dense.html) for `def symarray(prefix, shape)`. Note that this function returns a `numpy` n-dimensional array.